# rounding error in codeigntier controller

Tags: php, codeigniter

I made `round($data['c']) = $data['a'] + $data['b']` in my controller but when i run it, i got error like this :

```
Fatal error: Can't use function return value in write context in...
```

How to fix this ?

Answer (score 1):

`round()` function is return rounded value, you can only pass values into function using function params

in your expression: `round( $data['c'])`  is evaluate any number `(4)`, this is constant value, you can't assign value into constant number.

Try this way

```
$data['c'] = round($data['a'] + $data['b']);
```

Comment: To be exact, You're trying to assign a value to the round() function. the round() function returns a round number, you cannot assign to it, such as `round($int) = 55` , as this statement makes no sense.

Answer (score 1):

You should round the resulting value first before storing it into a variable:

```
$data['c'] = round($data['a'] + $data['b']);
```